# Defining my own concat

Tags: haskell

I'm reading a book and it asked me to define my own `concat` function.  I defined it correctly here:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat [] = []
-- concat [[]] = []
concat (xs:xss) = xs ++ (Main.concat xss)
```

I have two questions about this.

1. Why don't I need that line I commented out?
2. When I call this with `Main.concat [[]]`, step by step, how is it evaluated?  The way I think about it, it goes into the 2nd definition, but I can't make sense of that.  If I'm right and it goes to the 2nd definition, what are the values of `xs` and `xss`?

Comment: hint: `[] ++ [] == []`

Comment: Hint 2: `[x1,x2,x3,x4,...,xn] = x1 : x2 : x3 : x4 : ... : xn : []`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I'm right and it goes to the 2nd definition, what are the values of `xs` and `xss`?

Let's ask:

```
> f (xs:xss) = (xs, xss)
> f [[]]
([],[])
```

So now try substituting these values into your definition:

```
concat (xs:xss) = xs ++ (Main.concat xss)
                = [] ++ (Main.concat [] )
                = [] ++ []
                = []
```

Answer (score 3):

`[[]]` can also be written as `[] : []` (using the `(:)` constructor) -- that is, the list whose head is the empty list and whose tail is the empty list. So this can successfully pattern match against `xs:xss`.

So after matching `xs` with `[]` and `xss` with `[]`, we effectively get the following behavior:

```
let xs = [] in
  let xss = [] in
    xs ++ (Main.concat xss)
```

And with substitution, we get

```
[] ++ (Main.concat [])
```

That recursive call will hit the base case and thus return `[]`, giving `[] ++ []` and eventually `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR:** `[[]] = [] : []` just as `[1] = 1 : []`, so it matches the `x:xs` pattern.

In Haskell a list is defined as so:

```
data [a]    -- a list of `a`s is...
  = []      -- an empty list...
  | a : [a] -- or an `a`, then a list of `a`s.
```

When we write `[1,2,3]`, this is just syntactic sugar for `1 : (2 : (3 : []))`, and since `:` is what we call *right-associative*, we can also just write `1:2:3:[]`.

For this reason there are only two cases that are normally required when pattern matching on lists: `[]` and `(x:xs)`. `[]` is obviously the empty list, and `(x:xs)` is a non-empty list, where `x` is the first element and `xs` is the rest of the list.

Let's examine that definition, ignoring the commented line. I've removed some unnecessary brackets, by the way:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat []     = []                  -- The empty list case
concat (x:xs) = x ++ Main.concat xs -- The nonempty list case
```

We see that you've actually covered all the cases: this is now defined for all lists, so at least in theory the case `concat [[]] = []` is redundant.

In practice this is also true, because `concat [[]] = [] ++ concat [] = []` anyway, which falls into the second line's case, since `[[]] = [] : []` which matches the `(x:xs)` pattern.